# Angular 13 Project not loading some pages when production build deployed

Tags: angular, angular13

I have migrated our Angular project from 5.2 to 13. The migration went smooth and ng build / ng serve works well like it did before.

The real problem, where I don't know how to start working on it, is after I build the app for production (ng build --configuration production). The landing page of the project is completely blank, no JS errors, no console warnings.

Any relevant experience you might have in the past will help me, thanks a lot!

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^8.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^5.4.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.7.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^4.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.1",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.19",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "js2xmlparser": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.8",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  }
}
```

angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "app1"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app1",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "sky.theme.css",
        "modal.less"
      ],
  
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>OST</title>
  <base href="#">


  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules//@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" /> -->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=3">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/all.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>


<body>
  <app1-root></app1-root>
</body>

</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app1-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.navigate([''])
      } 
  title = 'app1';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// import '@progress/kendo-ui';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert-loader/alert/alert.component';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './alert-loader/confirm/confirm.component';
import { LoaderService } from './alert-loader/loader.service';
import { LoaderComponent } from './alert-loader/loader/loader.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AuditModuleService } from './modularWorkflow/audit-module/audit-module.service';
import { AuditTopicService } from './modularWorkflow/audit-topic/audit-topic.service';
import { NavitemService } from './modularWorkflow/audit-topic/navigation/activity-navigation/navitem.service';
//import { NavitemComponent } from './modularWorkflow/audit-topic/navigation/activity-navigation/navitem/navitem.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './modularWorkflow/commonPages/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './modularWorkflow/commonPages/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { EntityManagerService } from './modularWorkflow/entityManager/entity-manager.service';
import { EventEmitterService } from './modularWorkflow/event-emitter/event-emitter.service';
import { MaintenanceService } from './modularWorkflow/Maintenance/maintenance.service';
import { PermissionService } from './modularWorkflow/permission/permission.service';
import { PermissiondeniedComponent } from './modularWorkflow/permission/permissiondenied/permissiondenied.component';
import { UserRolePermissionGuard } from './modularWorkflow/permission/user-role-permission.guard';
import { ResourceManagerService } from './modularWorkflow/resourceManager/resourceManager.service';
import { DesignerService } from './modularWorkflow/audit-topic/navigation/activity-navigation/activity-designer/designer.service';
import { PaneModeService } from './modularWorkflow/shared/pane-mode.service';
import { WorkFlowModuleService } from './modularWorkflow/WorkFlowModule/work-flow-module.service';
import { QuickWorkFlowService } from './modularWorkflow/quick-work-flow/quick-work-flow.service';
import { AppInsightsService } from './monitoring/app-insights.service';
import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './core/common/error-handler/global-error-handler';
import { CountryLoginComponent } from './country-login/country-login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CKDRulesConfigService } from './modularWorkflow/ckd-rules/ckd-rulesConfig.service';
import { GlobalService } from './global.service';
import { DirectAccessGuardService } from './app-routing/direct-access-guard.service';
import { HelpComponent } from './alert-loader/help/help.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { RequestCache } from './cache-interceptor/request-cache.service';
import { CacheInterceptor} from './cache-interceptor/cache-interceptor.service';
import {CacheUrlHeaderCreator} from  './cache-interceptor/cache-createurlheader.service' 
import { HelpService } from './alert-loader/help/help.service';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import { CkdModulesComponent} from './modularWorkflow/ckd-rules/ckd-modules/ckd-modules.component';
import { MaterialModule} from './material/material.module';
import { CKDRulesConfigModule} from './ckd-rules-config/ckd-rules-config.module';
import { AddEditAllRulesComponent } from './modularWorkflow/ckd-rules//add-edit-all-rules/add-edit-all-rules.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './modularWorkflow/commonPages/footer/footer.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        BreadcrumbComponent,
        BreadcrumbsComponent,
        LoaderComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ConfirmComponent,
        PermissiondeniedComponent,
        CountryLoginComponent,
        HelpComponent,
        CkdModulesComponent,
        AddEditAllRulesComponent,
        FooterComponent        
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CKEditorModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        FormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        CKDRulesConfigModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(), deps: [ConfigService], multi: true },
        PaneModeService,
        NavitemService,
        EntityManagerService,
        AuditTopicService,
        ResourceManagerService,
        DesignerService,
        WorkFlowModuleService,
        LoaderService,
        HelpService,
        EventEmitterService,
        AuditModuleService,
        MaintenanceService,
        QuickWorkFlowService,
        PermissionService,
        UserRolePermissionGuard,
        AppInsightsService,
        GlobalService,
        CKDRulesConfigService,
        DirectAccessGuardService,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        RequestCache,
        CacheUrlHeaderCreator,
       {provide :HTTP_INTERCEPTORS , useClass:CacheInterceptor,multi:true }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Do you have any custom ErrorHandler classes in your app? By default, Angular should capture and display errors in the console. So a blank screen with a blank console would suggest human written code is blocking the errors from reaching the console.

Comment: Did you delete node  modules and then run npm i again? Also can you post a screenshot of the console?

Comment: Show your main.ts, index.html, AppModule and AppComponent here. Why we need tsconfigs?

Comment: added main.ts,index.hmtl, appmodule and appcomponent.

Comment: @Callan nothing is coming up in console

Comment: Angular 5.2 to Angular 13 is a long chain of updates. I recommend updating one  version at a time, and testing each update individually. Did the app break from 12 to 13, or was it between earlier versions? There are several major changes in there, such as Ivy between v8 and v9, as well as bundling changes in v13 (and many others).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?